# How to check if IO.popen succeeded?

Tags: ruby, popen

How can I check if creation of an IO object with IO.popen succeeded? For example the following fails, but an IO object is still created:

```
io = IO.popen("foobar", "w+")
io.inspect
```

Is there any way to find out if popen() actually succeeded?

Comment: How can IO.popen fail and return something at the same time? Are you sure that io.inspect doesn't return "nil"? BTW, the code above works for me exactly as excpected: the first line throws exception, the second one returns "nil". I'm on ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32].